# How can I run patch through a heredoc in bash?

Tags: patch, here-document

I'm trying to patch a file like this in bash:

```
cat << ''EOF | patch --dry-run
> --- urancid     2017-12-06 09:56:33.000000000 -0600  patch --dry-run
> +++ /tmp/urancid        2017-12-06 15:06:57.000000000 -0600
> @@ -393,7 +393,7 @@
>          last if (/^$prompt/);
>          next if (/-ac\.\s*/);
>          next if (/-fs\.\s*/);
> -       next if (/set date\s*/)
> +       next if (/set date\s*/);
>          next if (/^(\s*|\s*$cmd\s*)$/);
>          if ( ! /^$prompt/) {
>                  if ( ! $skipprocess ) {
> EOF
```

but all I get is

```
patching file urancid
Hunk #1 FAILED at 393.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file urancid.rej
```

Seems like it should be possible, if I cat the patch file I'm pasting it works.

I want to do this so I can make a patch script without including multiple files.

I'm not too familiar with the what "patch" cares about as far, guessing there's some whitespace problems?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixing up the whitespace in your example so that the patch can apply demonstrates that the concept is acceptable (although `cat` isn't needed as you can just `patch --dry-run <<'EOF'`).

On the other hand, if you have a patch that has badly aligned whitespace, I'd suggest you use the `--ignore-whitespace` parameter. (You can find this in the man page for patch, `man patch`.)

```
patch --dry-run --ignore-whitespace << 'EOF'
...
...
EOF
```